# ¿Peticiones con JS a la API que está fuera de la carpeta public_html?

Tags: javascript, php, api, fetch

¡Hola! Estoy aprendiendo a crear API REST en php con composer. Llevo un par de horas buscando acerca de este tema y me gustaría saber cómo debo **realizar peticiones con js** en el Hosting...

En el Localhost me funciona correctamente el manejo de directorios porque tengo disponible la carpeta raíz, pero obviamente en producción tengo sólo el dominio que apunta a la carpeta public_html.

*Ejemplo localhost: http://localhost/stackoverflow/public_html/ -
Ejemplo servidor: *https://stackoverflow.com/**

Mi directorio raíz consta de la siguiente manera:

|-api

|-public_html

|-index.php (recibe ruta por método GET)

**Mi pregunta es:**
¿Cómo y cuál es la forma correcta de enviar peticiones al index.php que está en la raíz con fetch?

Comment: Desde el navegador no puedes acceder a carpetas que están fuera de la carpeta raíz, que es la única con acceso público.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la práctica que se realiza aquí?, me gustaría saber donde puedo hallar información estándar acerca de un backend API tipo mvc, ¿Cómo puedo tener mi API más segura si no es fuera de la carpeta public_html?

Comment: La seguridad no depende 100% de la ubicación de archivos, sino de cómo manejas las peticiones y verificas roles y permisos. Para poder acceder a la API desde el navegador, debe estar en una ruta pública.

Comment: @Triby ¿Debo ubicar mi API en la carpeta public_html? Siendo ese el caso, ¿por qué hacen la estructura de carpetas así?

Algo que he probado es que con php sí puedo acceder al directorio raíz pero no sé cómo es exactamente el procedimiento que debo realizar para enviar por ejemplo mi formulario usando js

Comment: ¿Debes ubicar la API en carpeta pública? Solo si quieres tener acceso a ella. ¿Por qué hacen la estructura de carpetas así? Depende de quién la haga y cuál sea la finalidad de la API. PHP sí puede acceder a la carpeta raíz, porque se ejecuta en el servidor.

Comment: Caramba, el backend sí que me está dando unos buenos golpes. Gracias  @Triby